# Transfer files between a Mac with Apple silicon and another Mac

Tags: mac, file-transfer, apple-silicon

I'm trying to follow this guide here.
https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/transfer-files-a-mac-apple-silicon-mchlb37e8ca7/mac

I have Disk Utility up on my Apple silicon Mac, but I don't see Start Sharing option anywhere. Is there a screenshot of this action?

> 6. Select the disk or volume that you want to share, then click Start Sharing.

Comment: iirc, *Utilities > Share Disk* is a menu item in the recovery environment, not the Disk Utility app. [Can't check right now]

Comment: Those instructions don't mention Disk Utility. The Start Sharing should be in Utilities > Share Disk. In Recovery Mode. I was 17 seconds too slow :)